# file descriptor problem with looping bash script

Tags: bash

I've inherited a script that does this in a function:

```
# IO redirection for logging.
#touch $LOGFILE
exec 6>&1           # Link file descriptor #6 with stdout.
                # Saves stdout.
exec > $LOGFILE     # stdout replaced with file $LOGFILE.

touch $LOGERR
exec 7>&2           # Link file descriptor #7 with stderr.
                # Saves stderr.
exec 2> $LOGERR     # stderr replaced with file $LOGERR.
```

Later on in the function it does this:

```
#Clean up IO redirection
exec 1>&6 6>&-      # Restore stdout and close file descriptor #6.
exec 1>&7 7>&-      # Restore stdout and close file descriptor #7.
```

The problem is if I call this function twice (i.e. in a loop) the second iteration stops at the first set of code above without showing an error.

Why would it be doing that?

Comment: I’m still not 100% sure what you mean.  (A car stops when the driver steps on the brake, and it stops when it runs out of fuel –– do you see the difference?)  More importantly, does my correction fix the problem?  If not, what have you done to debug it?  (Other suggestions: put `$LOGFILE` and `$LOGERR` into quotes; i.e., `"$LOGFILE"` and `"$LOGERR"`.  And if you intend to capture _all_ the output from the function in the `$LOG` files (as opposed to just the _last_ call), the second (third) command should be “`exec >> "$LOGFILE"`” and the fifth (sixth) one should be “`exec 2>> "$LOGERR"`”.)

Answer (score 1):

I’m not exactly sure why it would “stop”, whatever you mean by that (does the script exit? hang?), I do see a problem: the last line should be `exec 2>&7 7>&-`. 
(Also, the comment on that line should say “stderr” rather than “stdout”.)

Comment: By "stop" I mean the script stops executing after these lines with no further output and no error message